# How to change my manipulator to global?

Tags: 3d, maya

Can I know how to change the manipulator from the current local status to global? Unable to do it via clicking right button and getting the local/global options (the option doesn't appear). Please help Thanks.

This is how the manipulator currently looks. I want to adjust it to global so that the green arrow points straight up and the red arrow points straight left forming a right angle.

Image:

[image]

New Image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several axes you can use for manipulation, and they all have their own place. **World** is the one you describe. The other common one is **Local**, which is relative to your selected object's parent.

Access the **Tool Settings** panel by double-clicking the move tool from the toolbox, and change the **Move Axis** to **World**:

[image]

One other way to access this setting is to hold down the <kbd>W</kbd> key in the viewport and drag the left mouse button to the left to access **World**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The tool settings works. But holding down W doesn't give me the global/local settings. edited the question to just show you the options I get when holding down W.

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like you're using the right (secondary) mouse button. Use the left (primary) and you should get the correct menu